# Django additional views in Django admin - URL trouble

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls, django-1.9

I'm adding an additional view to `django-admin`. My goal is to override the `change_form` to make the fields read only and add some custom forms to it for working with the `foreign_key` objects, and to also have an edit page which would be the additional view I'm creating.

I used this to start myself off but I've run into an issue already, probably because of the Django version I'm using.

http://patrick.arminio.info/additional-admin-views/

The issue I'm having is

```
TypeError at /admin/customers/order/1/review/
review() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. My code is here:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    review_template = 'review.html'

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(OrderAdmin, self).get_urls()
        review_urls = patterns('',
            (r'\d+/review/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.review)),
        )
        return review_urls + urls

    def review(self, request, id):
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=id)

        return render_to_response(self.review_template, {
            'title': 'Review order: %s' % order.id,
            'entry': order,
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'root_path': self.admin_site.urls,
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm new to Django and most useful information is in the Book, not the docs, which is far to long for Django to call itself *The web framework for perfectionists with deadlines.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url pattern does not capture any values, so does not have anything to pass onto the view method. You need to use capturing parentheses:

```
 r'(\d+)/review/$',
```

although usually you would use a named group to send the value as a keyword argument:

```
r'(?P<id>\d+)/review/$',
```